# paste code with syntax colors and alignment

Tags: c++, blogs

I am looking for some blog site where i will be able to directly paste c++ code examples 
in my publishes and see the code with all the alignments and colors like i see it on pastie.org.

I need all those things be made automatically because i don't know HTML and can't make by myself the code changes.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for blogging software? Or do you just want to post code snippets to show people? If the latter, try http://dpaste.com/

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself good enough. I want to pasted code snippets in blog . And that they will look like here for example 
http://code.google.com/p/syx/wiki/ExampleEmbeddingLua 
thanks

Comment: That's exactly what WP-Syntax does...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get [wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) + [WP-Syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/).

You won't be able to "copy and paste" the code directly, but you'll have to wrap it like this:

```
<pre lang="c++">
    CODE GOES HERE
</pre>
```

Comment: I had trouble to  use that wordpress app . It wants me to establish some web server , I look only some site where i can directly copy paste without further installations .

Comment: @Night Walker, you don't have to host the server yourself. If you get an account on wordpress.com you can let them host the blog for you.

Comment: I downloaded  that wordpress app , and had trouble to understand what to do with it there is only php files there .

Comment: Well if you want a blog, you can host it yourself by following the installation directions for blog software (like wordpress), or you can turn to a service that does the hosting for you: blogspot.com, wordpress.com, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I use [this](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) JavaScript for syntax highlighting in blogger. It's very easy to use.

The key feature of above highlihter is that script permanently hosted on http://softwaremaniacs.org/, so that make it possible is to use script on blogger.com.

Another one [nice syntax highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/) could be found at code.google.com (it could be integrated in blogger.com).
[image]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](http://syntaxhighlighter.googlecode.com/files/Overview01.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I use the "Online syntax highlighting" at http://tohtml.com
Paste your code in the text box there, select the programming language and color scheme and it will generate a webpage with your syntax highlighted code. Copy and paste that into your blogger editor and you are good to go.